# submit code in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i try to approve documents through dropdownlist...

when i select approve/reject/pending then i have submit button when i click on button  document will be approve/reject...what should i code on submit button??

here is the code of dropdown

```
 protected void DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = sender as DropDownList;

        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl.NamingContainer;
        if (ddl.SelectedValue == "Approved")
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new 
             SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
                ["mydms"].ConnectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    string selectedValue = ((DropDownList)
                   (row.FindControl("DropDownList4"))).SelectedValue;
                    //int rowindex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("approved", con);
                    docc.approve(Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]),
                      Convert.ToInt32(Session["DocID"]), 
                  Convert.ToInt32(Session["ApproveID"]), 
                   Convert.ToString(Session["Login2"]));
                    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (result != 0)
                    {
                        GrdFileApprove.DataBind();
                    }
                }


                catch
                {
                    apfi.Text = "Not Approve";



                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        else if (ddl.SelectedValue == "Reject")
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new 
    SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings

           ["mydms"].ConnectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    string selectedValue = ((DropDownList)
                      (row.FindControl("DropDownList4"))).SelectedValue;
                    //int rowindex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("approved", con);
                    docc.approve(Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]), 
                Convert.ToInt32(Session["DocID"]), 
             Convert.ToInt32(Session["ApproveID"]), 
               Convert.ToString(Session["Login2"]));
                    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (result != 0)
                    {
                        GrdFileApprove.DataBind();
                    }
                }


                catch
                {
                    apfi.Text = "Rejct";
                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

any solution?

Comment: I guess people like to read cleaner code ..

Comment: I don't understand the question. The dropdown SelectedIndexChanged callback does all the work on postback, why would you need submit button?

Comment: Even I don't understand your exact question but still I guess it is related to the Postback after Submit button clicked. When we click on Submit button,postaback occurs and the DropDown selected item will be chnaged due to this and setted automatically to index 0. So you have to avoid DropDown binding from Postback by either using !IsPostBack or use Update Panel of the Ajax Toolkit.

Comment: @Robert because when i select approve or reject once  in grid view to all documents and click on submit button then all action are performed through one button....